# Py2app is not finding the working directory

Tags: python, scrapy

I keep get this error when i run my py2app. It works when i do `python app.py` and when it runs as a terminal, however it doesnt work when its built to work as an py2app

[image]

It's a scrapy project.

**app.py**

```
import os
from subprocess import call


def main():
    cw = os.getcwd()
    path = '/scrape'
    cwd = cw + os.path.join(path)
    ourPath = ['scrapy','crawl', 'yellow']
    name = "yellow"
    call(["scrapy", "crawl", "{0}".format(name)], cwd=cwd)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrape` package isn't included in `/Contents/Resources` folder.
Since `app.py` doesn't include any names from the `scrape` package, the module graph that is constructed when building the application bundle doesn't consist it.

Build procedure can be updated to include the scrape package using the `--package` option passed to `py2app`. <sup>[[1]](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#option-reference)</sup>

However when `--package` option is provided, `scrapy` package will be copied in
`Contents/Resources/lib/python2.X/`. <sup>[[2]](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/implementation.html#create-the-app-bundle)</sup>

This means that you'll have to resolve the directory of the subprocess command for run in to this new path.

A better way to go about this is to run the scraper directly via the Crawler API and not as a subprocess command where that is feasible. <sup>[[3]](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)</sup> With the approach, py2app builds the module graph to include necessary code from `scrape` package.

Comment: so the solution would be to build the p2app with the `--package` option ?

Comment: Yes, that'd be one way to go about it.